# Flash Builder 4.5 how to get gps coordoninates?

Tags: mobile, flash-builder, flex4.5

The last version of Flash Builder (4.5) can generate mobile apps. 
How can I access to the geolocalistation? in Action Script 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this : 
http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/sensors/Geolocation.html

Next time make some search before asking

Answer (score 2):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/sensors/Geolocation.html

Same as the other answer, 'cept it isn't **ALL IN FRENCH**.